# Python [Bokeh charts] Heatmap ranges & coloring

Tags: python, charts, heatmap, bokeh

I would like to represent my data (which consist of 256 values) using a bokeh heat map where each value has its own color (so every item with the same value should have the same color).

I've been experimenting and bokeh is doing ranges for me such as the range between 24 - 47 has the same color and so on, but i wish to have a color for each value.

What is the best way to approach this problem? 
I've been experimenting with palettes and some perform way better than others, for example Inferno256 is doing a good job but is that the correct way to solve this? I mean is there a way to tell the chart/heat-map to display every value with a color (specify ranges?) or should i for example define a palette of 256 colors any thoughts?

Example where bokeh create big ranges for me:

```
Data=column_of_values[:1000]
data = {'fruit': [1]*len(Data), # Sections 
        'fruit_count': Data, 
        'sample': list(range(1,len(Data)+1))} 
hm = HeatMap(data, x='sample', y='fruit', values='fruit_count', palette=bp.Plasma11 , title='Fruits', stat=None)

hm.width=5000
output_file('heatmap.html')
show(hm)
```

The second part of my question (if possible), does bokeh handle big data well? 
forexample plotting 1000 values is different from plotting 10,000 using the same code, the values seem to be smashed together or something, should I fix that by expanding the width or something else :-) 
[Heat map plotting 1000 values then 10,000 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuwIm.jpg)